# Could not delete row or value as per required condition using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to delete some row or set value as null from the table using Angular.js. I am providing my code below:

```
 <tbody id="detailsstockid">
      <tr ng-repeat="d in days">
        <td>{{d.day_name}}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_category" name="answer_{{$index}}_category" ng-model="answer.category" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCategory track by cat.value" ng-change="removeBorder($index,answer.category.value,$parent.$index)" ng-init="renderWithMode($index,answer.category.value,$parent.$index,isEditMode)">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_subcategory" name="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" ng-model="answer.subcategory" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCategory[$parent.$index][$index] track by sub.value">
                    <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <!--<input type="text" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_comment" name="answer_{{$index}}_comment" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="answers.comment">-->
                  <input type="text" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_comment" name="answer_{{$index}}_comment" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="answer.comment">
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td style="width:20px">
                  <input ng-show="d.answers.length>1" class="btn btn-sm btn-red" type="button" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" style="text-align:center;" ng-click="removeRow(d.answers, $index,$parent.$index)"> 
                </td>
                <td ng-show="$last">
                  <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="text-align:center;" ng-click="addNewRow(d.answers)">  
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answer_{{$index}}_check" ng-model="answer.check" ng-checked="answerIsSelected($parent.$index, $index)" ng-click="toggleAnswerSelected($parent.$index, $index)" ng-disabled="isDisabled($parent.$index, $index)" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" style="margin-left:10px;"> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Here I have the table row like two dimensional array. I am providing my controller side code below:

```
$scope.days=[];
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=day",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        //console.log('day',response.data);
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj) {
      obj.answers = [];
      obj.chkbox=[];
      $scope.addNewRow(obj.answers);
      $scope.days.push(obj);
      $scope.selectedAnswers.push(obj);
    });
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
    }

   $scope.addNewRow = function(answers,hasDelete) {
    answers.push({
      category: null,
      subcategory: null,
      comment: null,
      //hasDelete: hasDelete ? hasDelete : false
    });
  };

  $scope.removeRow = function(answers, index,parent){
      //console.log('index',$index);
    answers.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent].splice(index,1);
    //answers.splice(answers.length-1,1);
  };

  $scope.renderWithMode = function(index,catvalue,parent,isEditMode){
    if(isEditMode){
      $scope.removeBorder(index,catvalue,parent);
    }
  };
  $scope.listOfSubCategory = []; 
  $scope.removeBorder=function(index,catvalue,parent,com){
    console.log('ind',index,catvalue,parent,document.getElementById('answer_'+index+'_'+parent+'_comment').value);
    if(catvalue !=undefined){
      //console.log('catvalue',catvalue!='');
       var subcategories=[];
         var catdata=$.param({'action':'subcat','cat_id':catvalue});
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:"php/customerInfo.php",
                data:catdata,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response){

                angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
                    var data={'name':obj.subcat_name,'value':obj.subcat_id};
                    if(!$scope.listOfSubCategory[parent]){
                $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent] = [];  
            }
                    //console.log('data',data);
                    subcategories.push(data);
                })
                $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent][index]=subcategories;
            },function errorCallback(response) {
            }) 
    }
  }
```

Here `$scope.days` have value like below.

```
$scope.days=[{'day_id':1,'day_name':'Monday'},{'day_id':2,'day_name':'Tuesday'},{'day_id':3,'day_name':'Wednesday'},{'day_id':4,'day_name':'Thursday'},{'day_id':5,'day_name':'Friday'},{'day_id':6,'day_name':'Saturday'},{'day_id':7,'day_name':'Sunday'}]
```

Here I need to check each row, if the category value is `blank/null` and the day has more than one child value it will remove. If the day has only one child value and same condition category value is null, it will not remove but the subcategory value will reset. I was doing like below.

```
$timeout(function() {
            var parentLength=$scope.days.length;
            for(var i=0;i<parentLength;i++){
              var childLength=$scope.days[i].answers.length;
              for(var j=0;j<childLength;j++){
                if(childLength > 1){
                  if($scope.days[i].answers[j].category==null){
                    $scope.days[i].answers.splice(j,1);
                  }
                }else{
                  if($scope.days[i].answers[j].category==null){
                    $scope.days[i].answers[j].category=null;
                    $scope.days[i].answers[j].subcategory=null;
                    $scope.days[i].answers[j].comment='';
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }, 1000);
```

I did like above but it's not working as expected. My [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/fERdwOdy7OXbx5vHjbAA?p=preview) is given here.

Comment: First of all I would try to iterate answers from end to beginning.

Comment: With this code structure it is best you create a working plunker and others can help you better with that

Comment: @Yaser : Here is my [plunkr code](https://plnkr.co/edit/fERdwOdy7OXbx5vHjbAA?p=preview). Please check this.